# how javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkBoxes)

checkBoxes()

function checkBoxes() {

```
const triggerBottom = window.innerHeight / 5 * 4



boxes.forEach(box => {

    const boxTop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top



    if(boxTop < triggerBottom) {

        box.classList.add('show')

    } else {

        box.classList.remove('show')

    }

})
```

}

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that _you_ have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Do you want to covert js to jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You must check [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/) to understand what's going on here:

```js
const boxes = $('.box')

$(document).on('scroll', checkBoxes)

checkBoxes()

function checkBoxes() {

const triggerBottom = window.innerHeight / 5 * 4

boxes.each(() => {

    const boxTop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top

    if(boxTop < triggerBottom) {

        $(this).addClass('show')

    } else {

        $(this).removeClass('show')

    }

})
```

References:

[`$`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) - selecting elements
[`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) - adding events
[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) - each element
[`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - add class
[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) - remove class

Comment: it doesn't work https://50projects50days.com/ day6 scroll-animation

Comment: Did you include jQuery script tag? (Example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: yes, I include jquery script tag